# Play Framework: URISyntaxException when passing special character from coffeescript

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

Currently I'm doing a search box in a project with Play Framework. I made a simple code that pass the search_box value in a "on input" and query the search result from server.

```
$(".search_box").on "input", (event) ->
LoadResult("/route_to_fetch_result/" + $(".search_box").val())
//LoadResult is a function that fetch json result returned by the search query.
```

The problem occurs when user inputted any of these special character ('[', ']', '#', '%', '/', '\' or '|') to the search box. As the function returned internal server error.

The error persists even after I put a "try-catch" block on the query and the function in the controller that didn't fire.

```
def getSearch_result(keyword: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    try{
        val searchList = Model.getSearch_result(keyword)
        Ok(Json.toJson(searchList))         
    }
    catch{ case _ => /*do return empty*/ }
}
```

The query function in the models

```
def getSearch_result(keyword: String): List[Search_result] = DB.withConnection{ implicit c =>
    try{
        SQL("""query LIKE {keyword}""").on('keyword -> ("%"+keyword+"%")).as(search_resultParser *)
    }
    catch{ case _ => /*do return empty*/ }
}
```

Directly opening the route with same parameter on the browser returned a URISyntaxException.

```
URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 22: /route_to_fetch_result/1[
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 22: /route_to_fetch_result/1[
 java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
 java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
 java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
 java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
 java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
 play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$1.path(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:98)
 play.docs.DocumentationHandler.maybeHandleDocRequest(DocumentationHandler.scala:58)
 play.docs.DocumentationHandler.maybeHandleDocRequest(DocumentationHandler.scala:28)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication.handleWebCommand(ApplicationProvider.scala:171)
 play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$1.apply(Server.scala:79)
 play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$1.apply(Server.scala:79)
 scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:124)
 scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:124)
 scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:102)
 scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Exception.scala:124)
 play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:79)
 play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:35)
 play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$8.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:117)
 play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$8.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:117)
 scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:98)
 play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:111)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
 com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459)
 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Currently I'm preventing the user to input special characters via a keypress event.
Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: @ejo `'keyword` is a special symbol which is correct syntax (it wouldn't compile without it). `'keyword'` is not, as single quotes are for character literals only. Double quotes are equivalent, but that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special characters are not valid in a URL. You need to encode them:

```
encodeURIComponent($(".search_box").val())
```

The same thing will happen if you have a route like this:

```
GET    /search/:keyword                  controllers.Page.search(keyword: String)
```

And you manually visit:

```
/search/bad[url
```

Results in:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path
```